# Bootstrap floating drops item onto second line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code: http://www.bootply.com/Tm5C3Ja7RL

```
<div class="col-md-12">
     <h3>Test</h3><button class="btn btn-default pull-right">Button</button>
</div>
```

It drops the button onto a second line as well as aligning it to the right. I only want to push it to the right. Can anyone show me the best way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As EWit mentioned, a header is a block element.
This block will push down other elements behind it.

There are several solutions, one better/cleaner than the other

**Changing the header to an inline element**

```
h3 {
    display:inline;
}
```

This will result in your title with the button right next to it.
I don't think the pull-right will have an effect on it. Should be tested.

You could also add the condition that the h3 must have a certain class or must be inside an element with a certain class.

**Splitting the column in 2**

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <h3>Test</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <button class="btn btn-default pull-right">Button</button>
</div>
```

By also using col-sm, for example, you could alter this so that the button is displayed next to the title in a medium/large screen and under it in a small screen.
However, the pull-right might make it look pretty weird then.

```
<div class="col-md-10 cold-sm-12">
    <h3>Test</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12">
    <button class="btn btn-default pull-right">Button</button>
</div>
```

**Put the button in the h3-element**

As EWit mentioned, you can also put the button inside the h3-element.
This will keep the button in the same line, but might alter the text formatting.

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <h3>Test <button class="btn btn-default pull-right">Button</button></h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put it inside the `<h3>`. Headers in HTML take up the full width as a block object. As such other objects are pushed down.

Try:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
     <h3>Test <button class="btn btn-default pull-right">Button</button></h3>
</div>
```

I myself extend it with some markup for basic links but to align it to the same height as the text in the header.

```
h1 .pull-right {
    padding: 15px 5px 0 0;
}
```

But I have no idea what values would be best for a button to align it. Trial and error I guess.